# How can i find the path helper from specific route i have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a specific path helper that works perfectly in rails 2.3 but throws error on rails 3.1.

Here is the path helper.

```
shipping_price_store_return_path(store)
```

When i use this in rails 3.1 it gives me error saying

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `shipping_price_store_return_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x007fb2da730228>
```

when i run rake routes This is whati get  `shipping_price_store_return_index        /stores/:store_id/return/shipping_price(.:format)                                  {:action=>"shipping_price", :controller=>"return"}`

can anyone suggest what could be going wrong here.

below are the content of routes file

```
resources :stores do      
      resources :return do
        match :shipping_price, :on => :collection
      end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your resource name is :return instead of :returns that Rails decided to add the _index to any collection nested underneath. This change has been done from rails 3 onwards.

So the new rails 3 route should be:

```
shipping_price_store_return_index_path
```

If you want to avoid the `_index` then either you can use `resources :returns` or you can make it `resource :return`.

Comment: when i use this path i get error saying  undefined method `shipping_price_store_return_index_path' for main:Object

Comment: just run `rake routes` and check what path is it creating. If it is rails 3 then I am damn sure this should be the path for above resource

Comment: This is the path i get /stores/:store_id/return/shipping_price(.:format) when i run r = Rails.application.routes and r.routes.each { |x| puts x.path }.compact on console

Comment: Do you know how to run `rake routes`? If yes then please run it, it should give you a path like this: `shipping_price_store_return_index_path  POST  /stores/:store_id/return/shipping_price(.:format)  return#shipping_price `

Comment: when i run rake routes, here is what i got  shipping_price_store_return_index        /stores/:store_id/return/shipping_price(.:format)                                  {:action=>"shipping_price", :controller=>"return"}

Comment: The same path I have suggested, which means your path is correct but it has some other issues, please post the complete code where you have this.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked....this was helpful..have up voted as well as accepted your answer